# MySql: How to select rows where all values are the same?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
name |id | state
name1 12   4
name1 12   4
name2 33   3
name2 33   4
...
```

I want to select every name and id from table where state is **only** 4, that means *name1* is correct, because it only has two records with state 4 and nothing more. Meanwhile *name2* is wrong, because it has record with state 4 **and** record with state 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation as shown below:

```
SELECT name, id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name, id
HAVING SUM(state<>4)=0;
```

See a [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef69ad/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, id from mytable where id not in
(select distinct id from mytable where state <> 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need 2 sub queries .

1. select with group by name were state 4
2. select with group by name

compare the count if the count is same then select it

example : select name , count (name) from table where state = 4  as T1
          select name , count (name) from table   as T2
           select T1.name from T1 and T2 where T2.count = T1.count

Answer (score 0):

You can use not exists like this:

```
select distinct name, id 
from table1 a
where not exists (select *
                  from table1 b
                  where  a.id=b.id and state<>4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more general case you can use count distinct (with not exists or with a join):

```
select distinct name, id 
from table1 a
where not exists (
select *
from table1 b
where  a.id=b.id
group by id
HAVING count(distinct state)>1)
```